# There is error at statment bind_parameter in my code

Tags: php

In My code i am using a prepare statement using bind_result. In the following code i access all values on the carmake table. In that when I am going to access the admin name it gives me the error "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object". I have used this code previously. i used get_result at that time and it worked fine, but when I used bind_result it gives an error

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


        </script>

        <?php 
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['username1']))
        {

            include("../config/database.php");

            if(isset($_GET["page"])) 
                { 
                    $page  = $_GET["page"];
                    $rows_per_page = 10; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $page=1;
                 }
                                $start_from = ($page * 10) -10;     
                                $limit = ($page * 10);


            $query=$conn->prepare("SELECT   makeid,name,status,creation_date_and_time,created_by FROM carmake ORDER BY makeid desc LIMIT $start_from,10");
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result($makeid,$name,$status,$creation_date_and_time,$created_by);
            //$result=$query->get_result();

        ?>

        <?php

            ?>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table">
                              <tr>
                                <th width="6%" align="center" class="tbl_back"> Id</th>


                                <th width="12%" align="center" class="tbl_back">Name</th>

                                <th width="12%" align="center" class="tbl_back">Created by</th>

                                <th width="12%" align="center" class="tbl_back">Status</th>
                                <th width="12%" align="center" class="tbl_back">Edit</th>
                                <th width="12%" align="center" class="tbl_back">Delete</th>
                                </tr> 
        <?php

                                //$i = 0;

                while($query->fetch())
                {
                        /* Construct Data */

                     ?>
                <?php

                    /*$serviceid=$data['servicetype'];
                    $query2="select * FROM tblservicemaster where serviceid='$serviceid'";
                    $result2 = mysql_query($query2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
                    $leadservice=mysql_fetch_array($result2);*/
                ?>
                     <tr>

                        <td class="tbl_back1"><?php echo $makeid ?></td>
                         <td class="tbl_back1"><?php echo $name ?></td> 

                           <td class="tbl_back1"> <?php
                            $idd=$created_by;
                           $query1=$conn->prepare("select name,adminid from  admintable where adminid=?");
                            $query1->bind_param("i",$idd);  
                            $query1->execute(); 

                            $query1->bind_result($name,$adminid);
                            //$query1->store_result();

                            $query1->fetch();

                          /* $query1="select name from  admintable where id=".$data[4];
                           $result1=mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
                           $data1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);*/

                          echo $name; 

                          ?> </td> 




                        <td class="tbl_back1"><?php if($status==1){echo "Enabled";}if($status==0){echo "Disabled";} ?></td>         

                        <td class="celledit"><a href="edit_carmakepages.php?id=<?php echo $makeid; ?>"><center><img src="images/editsign.jpg"/></center> </a></td> 
                        <td class="celldelete"><a href="javascript:del_topic(<?php echo makeid; ?>)"><center><img src="images/deletesign.jpg"/></center> </a></td>





                        <?php   
                            //$i++; 
                        ?>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>
                <?php  

                } // end while


                /*else
                {   
        ?>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table">
                           <tr>
                                <th width="6%" align="center" class="tbl_back"> Id</th>


                                <th width="12%" align="center" class="tbl_back">Name</th>

                                <th width="12%" align="center" class="tbl_back">Created by</th>

                                <th width="12%" align="center" class="tbl_back">Status</th>
                                <th width="12%" align="center" class="tbl_back">Edit</th>
                                <th width="12%" align="center" class="tbl_back">Delete</th>
                                </tr> 

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="15" align="center" style=" color:red"  class="tbl_back12">
                        No Record Found
                        <!--<h4 class="aligncenter">No Record Found</h4>-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    }*/
                    ?>

        </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php } ?>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try completely changing the while loop

```
while($query->fetch()){
$row[] = array('makeid' => $makeid, 'status' => $status, 'creation_date_and_time' => $creation_date_and_time, 'created_by' => $created_by);
} //end while
```

then change the while loop in its current form to a foreach and assign $iss the value of the current iteration of the arrays 'created_by' value like this:

```
foreach($row as $resultsFromArray){
                    /* Construct Data */

                 ?>
            <?php

                /*$serviceid=$data['servicetype'];
                $query2="select * FROM tblservicemaster where serviceid='$serviceid'";
                $result2 = mysql_query($query2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
                $leadservice=mysql_fetch_array($result2);*/
            ?>
                 <tr>

                    <td class="tbl_back1"><?php echo $makeid ?></td>
                     <td class="tbl_back1"><?php echo $name ?></td> 

                       <td class="tbl_back1"> <?php
                        $idd=$resultsFromArray['created_by']; //<--- Notice the change here
                       $query1=$conn->prepare("select name,adminid from  admintable where adminid=?");
                        $query1->bind_param("i",$idd);  
                        $query1->execute(); 

                        $query1->bind_result($name,$adminid);
                        //$query1->store_result();

                        $query1->fetch();

                      /* $query1="select name from  admintable where id=".$data[4];
                       $result1=mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
                       $data1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);*/

                      echo $name; 

                      ?> </td> 




                    <td class="tbl_back1"><?php if($status==1){echo "Enabled";}if($status==0){echo "Disabled";} ?></td>         

                    <td class="celledit"><a href="edit_carmakepages.php?id=<?php echo $makeid; ?>"><center><img src="images/editsign.jpg"/></center> </a></td> 
                    <td class="celldelete"><a href="javascript:del_topic(<?php echo makeid; ?>)"><center><img src="images/deletesign.jpg"/></center> </a></td>





                    <?php   
                        //$i++; 
                    ?>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
            <?php  

            }// end foreach
```

Comment: i did the changes it gives mi first row coreectly but at second row on column created by it gives mi again same error

Answer (score 0):

Add th line  `$query->bind_param('i',$id);` If your id is makeid then you use $makeid in place of $id.

```
     $query=$conn->prepare("SELECT   makeid,name,status,creation_date_and_time,created_by FROM carmake ORDER BY makeid desc LIMIT $start_from,10");
 //Bind the variable to prepared statement
    $query->bind_param('i',$id); // i corresponds to integer type variable
                $query->execute();
                $query->bind_result($makeid,$name,$status,$creation_date_and_time,$created_by);
```

Use it if you are having an id column

Comment: it gives mi write makeid and name problem in accessing column created by

Comment: @Ravi Just edited the code. I hope this works. You were missing a bind statement.